# Post http request in angular 5

Tags: angular5

I am new to angular and have started in angular 5.I want to get some data from api using post method,below is my code

myhttp.interceptor.ts

```
import { Injectable, Injector } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler, HttpRequest } from 
'@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw'
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';

@Injectable()
export class MyhttpInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

constructor() { }
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): 
Observable<HttpEvent<any>>{

const authReq = req.clone({ headers: req.headers.set("X-API-KEY", 
"admin@123")});

return next.handle(authReq);
}
}
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule,routingComponents } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { PageNotFoundComponent } from './page-not-found/page-not- 
found.component';
import { DepartmentDetailComponent } from './department-detail/department- 
detail.component';
import { DepartmentOverviewComponent } from './department- 
overview/department-overview.component';
import { DepartmentContactComponent } from './department-contact/department- 
contact.component';
import { DepartmentdataService } from './departmentdata.service';
import {HttpClientModule,HTTP_INTERCEPTORS} from '@angular/common/http';
import {MyhttpInterceptor} from './myhttp.interceptor';


@NgModule({
declarations: [
AppComponent,
routingComponents,
PageNotFoundComponent,
DepartmentDetailComponent,
DepartmentOverviewComponent,
DepartmentContactComponent
],
imports: [
BrowserModule,
AppRoutingModule,
HttpClientModule
],
providers: [DepartmentdataService,
{ 
provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, 
useClass: MyhttpInterceptor, 
multi: true 
} ],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.component.ts from here i request to api

```
import { Component,OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
selector: 'app-root',
templateUrl: './app.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
title = 'routing and navigation demo';

constructor(private http: HttpClient){
}
ngOnInit(){
const req= 
this.http.post('http://example.com/pcs/api/vheicles',{})
.subscribe(res => {console.log(res);},err => {console.log('Error 
Occured');})
}
}
```

When i try to use above code it shows an error in console is-
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://example.com/pcs/api/vheicles' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Here when i write above vehicles api i pass X-API-KEY in header and here in interceptor i pass header as this,is it correct or any other pass to header in interceptor please help me.

Comment: That error is nothing to do with any of the code you've shown; the *server* nneds to be configured to handle CORS correctly.

Comment: But this api already used in developing android app

Comment: @dipti yes exactly as point noted in the comment: BTW which language you are using for developing API?

Comment: using php language

Comment: If i pass my local file path instead of server path in url ,it also return same CORS error,below is my local path                                                              const req= this.http.post('http://localhost/gatepass/index.php/admin/pass_lists',{})
.subscribe(res => {console.log(res);},err => {console.log('Error Occured');})